# I am getting PhpMailer sending error

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to send mail in Gmail using phpmailer from my websites contact form. And getting this error :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@' in
>   /home/dindaelectronics/public_html/mailer.php on line 19

Here is the PHP code, in which in line 19 has the error (which I am unable to understand).

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

$mail             = new PHPMailer();
$body             = file_get_contents('contact.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; 
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2; 
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
$mail->Port       = 26;
$mail->Username   = "yourname@yourdomain";  <--  **Line 19 which is indicating error**

$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";


$email_to = "debnil2014@gmail.com";

$email_subject = "Checking PHP Mailer";





function died($error) {

// your error code can go here

echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

echo $error."<br /><br />";

echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

die();

}



// validation expected data exists

if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||

!isset($_POST['address']) ||

!isset($_POST['email']) ||

!isset($_POST['mobile']) ||

!isset($_POST['subject']) ||

!isset($_POST['query'])) {

died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

}



$first_name = $_POST['name']; // required

$last_name = $_POST['address']; // required

$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

$telephone = $_POST['mobile']; // not required

$comments = $_POST['subject']; // required

$comments = $_POST['query']; // required


$error_message = "";

$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

$error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

died($error_message);

}

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



function clean_string($string) {

$bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

}



$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Address: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

$email_message .= "Mobile: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

$email_message .= "Subject: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

$email_message .= "Query: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";



// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->







<?php

}

?>
```

and Here is the HTML form...

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="mailer.php">
                            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
                            <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address" required></textarea>
                            <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email id" required>
                            <input name="mobile" type="text" placeholder="Mobile No." required>
                            <input name="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject" required>
                            <textarea name="query" placeholder="Query" required></textarea>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
                    </form>
```

So can anybody solve this?

Comment: `yourname@yourdomain` is not a valid email address. It shoudl be something like `yourname@yourdomain.com` for example

Comment: Are you sure about the eregi_replace line? You should use preg_replace for that and I think the backslash should be escaped!

Comment: @RiggsFolly yourname@yourdomain can be a perfectly valid email address: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses

Comment: if you are using gmail your the port should be `'587'` not `'26'` also try adding `$mail->isHTML();`

Comment: @Typoheads Yes but is it a valid `SMTP account username` in this guys case?

Comment: @RiggsFolly It could be. In any case, this shouldn't result in a "Parsing error" anyway, so I suspect the problem somewhere else.

Comment: I have implemented all you suggests, but still getting the same error. Also to mention that, I am trying to send mail from webmail to gmail using phpmailer!

Comment: @Typoheads no it can't since ICANN outlawed dotless domains a couple of years ago.

Comment: You've based your code on an an old example and are probably using an old version of PHPMailer. Start with [an up to date example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) and update PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, if you are trying to send through **GMail** then you should be configuring using **GMail's SMTP parameters** but if using your **webmail** then it should be your **host's SMTP parameters**.

```
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; 
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2; //Change this to "true" to also see your errors
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
$mail->Port       = 26;
$mail->Username   = "yourname@yourdomain";  <--  **Line 19 which is indicating error**

$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";
```

Another thing is, `[eregi_replace][1]` is deprecated.